# Can't open modal on new main page

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

This code fully demonstrates what looks like a bug. Sequence is...

1. App opens
2. Default main page created.
3. Login box popped up.
4. Login box closed. (Click on page to simulate)
5. New main page created.
6. Login box popped up.(Click on page to simulate)
7. Exception... Cannot access disposed object.

Any ideas?

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Xaml;

[assembly: XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
namespace test333
{
    public class Main1 : ContentPage
    {
        public Main1()
        {
            var btn = new Button();

            btn.Clicked += (sender, e) =>
            {
                MessagingCenter.Send<object>(this, "LoginLogout");
                Navigation.PopModalAsync();
            };
            Content = btn;
        }
    }

    public partial class App : Application
    {
        public App()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            MainPage = new Main1 { BackgroundColor = Color.Red };

            MessagingCenter.Subscribe<object>(this, "LoginLogout", s =>
                Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () => await HandleLogOut()));

            HandleLogOut();
        }

        bool login = true;

        async Task HandleLogOut()
        {
            if (login)
            {
                await MainPage.Navigation.PushModalAsync(new Main1 { BackgroundColor = Color.Orange });
            }
            else
            {
                MainPage = new Main1 { BackgroundColor = Color.Green };
            }

            login = !login;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: why did you post this instead of just editing your prior question?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55434586/cannot-access-a-disposed-object-when-calling-pushmodalasync

Comment: if you feel that its a bug, then file a bug report: https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem happens in  step 6:`Login box popped up.(Click on page to simulate)`.

Have a look at below codes in btn.clicked:

```
btn.Clicked += (sender, e) =>
            {
                MessagingCenter.Send<object>(this, "LoginLogout");

                Console.WriteLine("popAction");
                Navigation.PopModalAsync();
            };
```

And handle logout:

```
 async Task HandleLogOut()
        {
            if (login)
            {
                await MainPage.Navigation.PushModalAsync(new Main1 { BackgroundColor = Color.Orange });
                Console.WriteLine("PushModalAction");
            }
            else
            {
                MainPage = new Main1 { BackgroundColor = Color.Green };
            }

            login = !login;
        }
```

I print the `popAction` and `PushAction` in your code, you will find that the `popAction` is executed before `PushAction`.

**Solution:**

You should perform `popAction` after `pushModalAction` is completed.

I moved the `Navigation.PopModalAsync();` from the `btn.clicked` to `HandleLogOut` and then it works well.

```
   btn.Clicked += async (sender, e) =>
            {
                MessagingCenter.Send<object>(this, "LoginLogout");                            
            };
```

In handle logout:

```
async Task HandleLogOut()
{
    if (login)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("PushModalAction");
        await MainPage.Navigation.PushModalAsync(new Main1 { BackgroundColor = Color.Orange });

        Console.WriteLine("popAction");
        MainPage.Navigation.PopModalAsync();                

    }
    else
    {
        MainPage = new Main1 { BackgroundColor = Color.Green };
    }

    login = !login;
}
```

Comment: I came to a similar conclusion. The main page is switched before the modal has finished popping. But the corruption is not apparent until the next push is attempted. This doesn't result in an exception on Android but the pop animation is cut short. Academic really because I want the new main page to be built behind the popup, which means the pop up can't be part of the old main page.